# Recovering deja-dup encryption password

Tags: deja-dup, password-recovery

I have lost my encryption password for backup on deja-dup.

Please can you let me know how to recover it? By the way this is after a re-installation of ubuntu 11.10, so it is probable that the old file where the passwords were written is lost.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot. A 128 Bit password cannot be bruteforced with a normal computer, that would take many many years.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I had the same question and remembered ultimately finding an answer. I knew deja-dup had to cache the password somewhere or it couldn't apply the password each time it runs.

Assuming you are running Ubuntu (probably any modern Debian- or Red Hat-based linux system) you can open **Passwords and Keys**. Under **Login** you should see an item **Backup encryption password**. Double-click **Backup encryption password** and a modal dialog will open that will allow you to copy or view your key. This is where deja-dup stores your password so it can be applied to backups.

Password and Keys is provided by Seahorse under Gnome. I'm sure there is something similar (or the same) under KDE or XFCE if that's your desktop environment.

If you only have old backup files as a resource, then as the original response says, you're probably out of luck.